# Raspberry Pi - change keyboard shortcuts

Tags: raspberry-pi, keyboard-shortcuts, raspbian, shortcut, raspberry-pi4

on RPI its possible to open the terminal with keyboard shortcut CTRL+ALT+T.
Is there any way to change this shortcut to another combination or completely remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [key binding](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) by modifying `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`. So if you want want to run it with Alt+t you need to do:

```
 <keybind key="A-t">

  <action name="Execute">

    <command>lxterminal</command>

  </action>

</keybind>
```

And you could bind an existing shortcut to some other program.

There is a bunch of tutorials out there on this topic:

1. [Creating Custom Raspberry Pi OS Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/creating-custom-raspberry-pi-os-keyboard-shortcuts)
2. [How to Create Custom Keyboard Shortcuts for Raspberry Pi](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-custom-keyboard-shortcuts,40215.html)

Comment: Hi Bruno Golubic, I already tried this approach. I can also finde the terminal shortcut "C-A-T" in this file, but if I change it to "W-A-T" for example, the shortcut works still with control button, not with windows button.

Comment: Strange. Di you try to create some other shortcut that would use the W and that would run some other command/program? From some reading that I've done, I've found info that with some Linux distros this can be  [related to language settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231863/super-key-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04).